# update one file in a remote branch of Git repository but all branches were updated

Tags: git, github

I have two branches in a remote GIT (version 1.8.3.msysgit.0) repository.

One is master and another one is branch1.

I need to update single file at branch1.

I am on my local branch1.

But, after editing the file, I ran

```
 git add myfile
 git commit myfile
 git push
```

All branches in my remote repo were updated.

Why ? I only need to update one file in one branch.

thanks

**git branch -vv output:**

```
*branch1  xxxxx [origin/branch1] update readme
 master   xxxxx [origin/ ahead 1] update that should only be shown in branch1.
```

I have reverted the updated of master remotely. But, h**ow to remove the local commit for master because it should not be updated ?**

And, **how to remove all related records about the wrong update on master ? I do want to confuse my team members when they check out master**

output of

```
 git branch --contains $(git log --format=%h -n 1)
```

is

```
* branch1
```

**I need to remove the commit (ahead 1) on top of master because it is a wrong action result. I do not want to make any changes to master.**

Comment: Show the output of `git branch -vv`, please

Comment: What version of Git are you using? What is the output of `git config push.default` ?

Comment: git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0. Output of git config push.default is empty.

Comment: @user3601704 You might have merged your branch to master, show the output of this please `git branch --contains $(git log --format=%h -n 1)` This shows us if the top commit of the `branch1` branch is presented in master.

Comment: please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
git add file-name

git commit -am "Add new file"

git push origin branch name
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `push.default` setting is set to `matching` which means `git push` will push to **all** branches.

You might want to change it to `simple` (which is default since git 2.0)